# How to find min distance between line that doesn't intersect a plane

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry, intersection-theory

Good morning,

How would you find the **Min** distance between a line and a plane (if the line does NOT intersect the plane)?

E.g.

Q(s) = (1,2,3) + s(-2,1,-1)

Plane: 3a + 5b - c = -3

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Distance between a **point** and a plane is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane#Closest_point_and_distance_for_a_hyperplane_and_arbitrary_point

Answer (score 1):

Since $$(-2,1,-1)(3,5,-1)=0,$$ we see that the line is parallel to the plane.

Just take a point in the line (the point $(1,2,3)$ for example)  and find a distance between this point and the plane.

I got $$\frac{13}{\sqrt{35}}.$$

Comment: Sure. But how could you verify whether the distance between that specific point is the minimum distance between the line and the plane?

Comment: @Zac: if a line and a plane do not meet they're parallel. Which means that all points in the line have the same distance from the plane.

Answer (score 0):

You have a formula for the (min) distance of  point $M(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to the plane $(\Pi)$ with equation $ux+vy+wz+t=0$:
$$d(M,\Pi)=\frac{|ux_0+vy_0+wz_0+t|}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2+w^2\,}}.$$
If the line is parallel to the plane, this distance will be the same for all points of the line.